# std::ranges::algorithms differ in semantics compared to range-based for() loop in regard to the usage of a particular view

Tags: c++, for-loop, std-ranges, c++23

I wanted to view a 3x3 grid column by column, so I figured I would use `std::views::stride` like so:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

auto main() -> int {
    auto grid = std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>{{
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9}
    }};

    namespace vs = std::views;

    auto strideCount = grid.size();
    auto allElements = grid | vs::join;

    auto columns = vs::iota(0uz, strideCount)
                   | vs::transform([allElements, strideCount](auto n) {
                        return allElements
                                | vs::drop(n)
                                | vs::stride(strideCount);
                   });

    for (auto&& column : columns) {
        for (auto element : column) {
            std::cout << element << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

This works and prints:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

That is, it prints every element column by column.

In my original example I wanted to test whether each column satisfies a given criteria. Instead of a range-based `for ()` loop, I tried using `std::ranges::all_of()`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

auto main() -> int {
    auto grid = std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>{{
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9}
    }};

    namespace vs = std::views;

    auto strideCount = grid.size();
    auto allElements = grid | vs::join;

    auto columns = vs::iota(0uz, strideCount)
                   | vs::transform([allElements, strideCount](auto n) {
                        return allElements
                                | vs::drop(n)
                                | vs::stride(strideCount);
                   });

    std::ranges::all_of(columns, [](auto&& column) {
        for (auto element : column) {
            // logic that alters whether we return true or false
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

The only difference is that instead of:

```cpp
for (auto&& column : columns) {
    for (auto element : column) {
        std::cout << element << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I now have:

```cpp
std::ranges::all_of(columns, [](auto&& column) {
    for (auto element : column) {
        // logic that alters whether we return true or false
    }
    return true;
});
```

With the appropriate `#include <algorithm>`.

However, this unfortunately does not work. It fails here (in the `std::ranges::all_of()` snippet):

```cpp
for (auto element : column) {
```

With error claiming that:

```
error: passing 'const std::ranges::stride_view<std::ranges::drop_view<std::ranges::join_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> > > > >' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

For both `begin()` and `end()`.

However, if I instead of taking `auto&& column` take `auto column` in the lambda, the code compiles.

Why is it so? Why *can* I use forwarding reference for each column in the `for ()` loop example and *can't* do that in the lambda argument in `std::ranges::algorithm` cases?

I am using `gcc version 13.1.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-msvcrt-mcf-seh, built by Brecht Sanders)` (output of `g++ -v`).

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps (I'm really terrible at `ranges`) but the culprit seems to be `| vs::drop(n)`. Removing that makes it compile.

Comment: @TedLyngmo good to know that there is another workaround, however that part is quite essential for the solution.  Since those are views, copying (instead of taking each column by forwarding reference) them should be a sufficient workaround. Nonetheless, I am really curious what is the underlying cause for this inconsistency.

Comment: `auto&& column` is deduced equivalently to `const auto& column` in this case (because `columns` is a certain type of view). `column` is itself a view, and many types of views are not iterable if `const`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to keep a single dimensional array and `std::chunk(3)` it on demand?

Comment: @Eugene why is it deduced as `const` in the `ranges::all_of()` lambda case and *not* in the range-based `for ()` loop case?

Comment: @Red.Wave perhaps. Most probably it would be the best to have a 1d array with `std::mdspan` that emulates a 2d array wrapping over it. Nonetheless the problem is, I believe, disconnected from the exact type of `grid`.

Comment: @Fureeish I am just keeping it simple. In this snippet, the source range could simply be `std::iota` instead of an array.

Comment: @Fureeish That's a good question. I don't know. If I understood all the details, I would make it an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I only browsed through quickly either, sorry. But a little bit along the lines, what @Eugene already hinted at: when you take `(auto column)`, you should get a copy (whatever the copy of a view is in the end), non-`const`. `(auto &&column)` is a "universal reference", which boils down to a l-value-refrence when binding to a l-value - I currently don't recall when this is going to be a `const&`, though... ... `std::ranges::stride_view` features a `const` as well as a non-`const` `begin()`, both restricted by concepts. Maybe that leads somewhere? Is the complete error message more complex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is LWG [3996](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3996), for which [P2997](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2997r0.html) specifically provides proposed wording.

---

`ranges::all_of` requires the predicate `Pred` to satisfy `indirect_unary_predicate<Pred, projected<I, Proj>>`, which ultimately leads to

```
invocable<Pred&, iter_common_reference_t<projected<I, Proj>>>
```

must be satisfied, where `Proj` is the projection function.

Class template `std::projected` is a helper type used to construct a new iterator type whose reference type is the result of applying `Proj` (`std::identity` in most cases) to the `iter_reference_t<I>`, which facilitates the spelling of the requirements of the "rangified" algorithm ([[projected](https://eel.is/c++draft/projected)]):

```
namespace std {
  template<class I, class Proj>
  struct projected-impl {                               // exposition only
    struct type {                                       // exposition only
      using value_type = remove_cvref_t<indirect_result_t<Proj&, I>>;
      using difference_type = iter_difference_t<I>;     // present only if I
                                                        // models weakly_incrementable
      indirect_result_t<Proj&, I> operator*() const;    // not defined
    };
  };

  template<indirectly_readable I, indirectly_regular_unary_invocable<I> Proj>
    using projected = projected-impl<I, Proj>::type;
}
```

Let's go back to `invocable<Pred&, iter_common_reference_t<projected<I, Proj>>>`.

In your example, the original iterator `I`'s `reference` and `value_type` are both prvalue `stride_view`, so its common reference `iter_common_reference_t<I>` is also `stride_view`.

However, `projected<I, Proj>`'s `reference` and `value_type` are `stride_view&&` and `stride_view` respectively,  which makes the result of `iter_common_reference_t<projected<I, Proj>>` end up being calculated as `const stride_view&`. Since `stride_view` is not `const`-iterable, this results in a hard error during instantiation because we call `const stride_view`'s `begin` inside an unconstrained lambda.

This is a standard defect. It seems that we still need the proposed resolution of LWG [3859](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3859) to make `projected<I, std::identity>` just `I`, although it is marked as "Resolved by [P2609R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2609r3.html)", which is not the case in this case.

The workaround is to use a dummy `identity` that returns prvalue so that the common reference of the projected iterator is still a prvalue ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z9sKEcvvh)):

```
std::ranges::all_of(columns, [](auto&& column) {
    for (auto element : column) {
        // logic that alters whether we return true or false
    }
    return true;
}, [](auto r) { return r; });
```

Comment: Isn't this fix basically the same as omitting the projection entirely and taking `column` in the predicate by value?

Comment: Correct. This fix is based on working if the lambda accepts `auto&&`.

Comment: Cppreference claims that only msvc implemented p2609. I am using GCC, thus it probably works, just my tool of choice not yet up to date

Comment: @Fureeish Your original example will not work regardless of whether P2609 is implemented or not as it is a defect of the current standard.

Comment: Makes sense, I have initially misunderstood what you meant

Comment: @Fureeish An easier (if weirder) fix would be to just `[](auto&& column) -> bool {`. Adding the trailing-return-type prevents the constraint check from instantiating the body, without having to add a dummy extra projection. Also Hewill already updated the answer to link to mine and Tim's paper, which has a "fun" romp through why this constraint exists and how we want to fix this problem.

Comment: @Barry "Adding the trailing-return-type prevents the constraint check from instantiating the body [...]" - it does *what*? Either I have never heard of anything like this or I completely misunderstood what you mean by that. Do you perhaps have any additional sources on this?

Comment: @Fureeish `[](auto&& column) {` does not explicitly specify the return type of the lambda, so the compiler *needs* to instantiate the function body to deduce the correct return type, which causes `const begin` to be called. This is why the hard error occurs. `[](auto&& column) -> bool {` specifies the return type, so the compiler *does not need* to instantiate the function body to get the return type, so there will be no hard errors.

Comment: @康桓瑋 but the lambda body will have to be instantiated at some point. Definitely before the compilation is finished. So it matters *when* it is instantiated? Can you provide any materials containing any examples? Maybe a simplified version where this matters? I am still very surprised.